# Load of server having 2 CPUs

Tags: batch-file, cpu-usage

I have a server with 2*CPU. when i run below code on server it gives two CPU LoadPercentage value as:

**code:**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(For /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('"wmic cpu get LoadPercentage  /value  |find "P" "') do (
set "line=%%A %%B"
set "line=!line:~0,-1!"
echo !line!
))>output.txt
```

**output.txt:**

```
LoadPercentage 2
LoadPercentage 4
```

While on server in task manager->performance its showing only one value (obviously, as server is 1).
How this one value is showing while CPU's are two...? Is it average of two's..? How i can get that single value of CPU Load percentage using batch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's sum of loads divided by the number of processors.

In `for` loop, as you get the loads, sum them and count the number of cpus. On `for` exit, `set /a average=...` will give the answer.

EDIT (over the OP own answer)

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Initialize variables
    set sum=0
    set num=0

    rem Iterate over wmic output 
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%1 in ('wmic cpu get LoadPercentage /value ^|find "P" ') do (
        set /a sum=!sum!+%%1
        set /a num=!num!+1
    )

    rem test if we get any data
    if %num% gtr 0 (
        set /a avg=%sum%/%num%
    ) else (
        set avg=0
    )

    echo CPULoadPercentage %avg% > output.txt

    exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

Here..it works..

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set sum=0
(for /f "tokens=1-2* delims==" %%1 in ('"wmic cpu get LoadPercentage  /value  |find "P" "') do (
set /a sum=!sum!+%%2
)
set /a avg=!sum!/2
echo CPULoadPercentage !avg!
)>output.txt
exit /b
```

Comment: That will fail if number of processors is not two. Also, too much ( and ". It is easier. Please, see updated answer.